# How can I get webshot to work with bookdown?

Tags: r, phantomjs, bookdown

I am using `bookdown` to create a "book", in both PDF and HTML.

In places where I have a video for the HTML, I get this message when I render:

> Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
> Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
> HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
> your rmarkdown file:
>
> always_allow_html: true
>
> Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Following these instructions about `always_allow_html` seems to be discouraged by yihui (https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/440):

> You should not add always_allow_html: yes to YAML.

So, a search yields a solution (e.g. https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html):

> Since knitr v1.13, HTML widgets will be rendered automatically as screenshots taken via the webshot package (Chang 2019). Of course, you need to install the webshot package. Additionally, you have to install PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org), since it is what webshot uses to capture screenshots. Both webshot and PhantomJS can be installed automatically from R:

...and some instructions given, which I have followed.

So now, I have `webshot` and `phantomjs` download and installed by following those instructions, which is easily confirmed:

```
> webshot::is_phantomjs_installed()
[1] TRUE
> webshot:install_phantomjs()
It seems that the version of `phantomjs` installed is greater than or equal to the requested version.To install the requested version or downgrade to another version, use `force = TRUE`.
Error in webshot:install_phantomjs() : argument of length 0
```

Whether I use `webshot:install_phantomjs()` or `webshot:install_phantomjs(force=TRUE)`, nothing changes.

Indeed, this fails:

```
> webshot:install_phantomjs(version="2.1.1", force=TRUE)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   637  100   637    0     0           0   1585      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:---:-- --:--:--  1588
  0 16.3M  100 16.3M  100 16.3M    0     0  3244k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 3926k
0:01  0:10:39 49930phantomjs has been installed to /Users/pdunn2/Library/Application Support/PhantomJS
Error in webshot:install_phantomjs(version = "2.1.1", force = TRUE) : 
  argument of length 0
```

So... if `webshot` and `phantomjs` appear to be installed... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for direction...

P.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base         

other attached packages:
[1] webshot_0.5.2 bookdown_0.20

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] packrat_0.5.0    digest_0.6.25    jsonlite_1.7.0   magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.14    rlang_0.4.7      stringi_1.4.6   
 [8] curl_4.3         rstudioapi_0.11  rmarkdown_2.3    webshot_0.5.2    tools_4.0.2      stringr_1.4.0    xfun_0.15       
[15] yaml_2.2.1       rsconnect_0.8.16 compiler_4.0.2   askpass_1.1      htmltools_0.5.0  openssl_1.4.2    knitr_1.29
```

Comment: One option is to use an if statement to use one output for one format, and another for other formats. For a similar problem, I implement something like if latex output format, print(image).

Comment: Thanks Mark. While that is possible, I would prefer things to work as per the manual (and it *used* to work as described). 

I can also use the `children` approach. But it is a lot of extra work for my document, that should not be necessary.

So something has obviously gone wrong... and I'd really prefer things to be fixed.

Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: You could try running via rstudio cloud - that will confirm whether it is platform specific.

Comment: I can add that it was working last week and the platform has not changed.  So it does work on my Mac as of last week.I did update R to the latest versions... but no-one else has reported any issues...  Still confused!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `webshot` library solve my problem.
for example:

```
{r}
library(webshot)
DT::datatable(iris)
```

Funnily enough, I tried this solution after reading your reference. And it works like a charm. Thanks to you.